# What is the Prototype equivalent of JQuery's $(element).text()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, prototypejs, innerhtml

Given the following snippet:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  This is my text <span>with a span</span>
</div>
```

JQuery can get the interior string with:

```
$('#myDiv').text();
```

Is there a more intuitive way in Prototype than:

```
$('myDiv').pluck('innerHTML').first().stripTags();
```

Comment: just to mention it since I was googling for this: jQuery's text() function seems to be the perfect replacement / alternative / migration of prototype's stripTags() function

Answer (score 4):

Hum, doesn't

```
$('myDiv').innerHTML.stripTags();
```

work ?

Edit: if you really want a `text()` method in Prototype, you can do so :

```
Class.extend(Element, {
  text: function(element) {
    return element.innerHTML.stripTags();
  }
};
```

and then use it like this :

```
var txt = $('myDiv').text();
```

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's just that this seems so common a call, I expected a more streamlined way to get the information.

Comment: Well, the line with pluck is way more complicated than what I wrote.

Comment: Arriving from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225697/secure-node-js-chat-avoid-xss), and the [stripTags docs](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/String/prototype/stripTags/index.html) where it says: `good enough for most purposes, but you cannot rely on it for security purposes`. I wonder if it is the exact same thing as jQuerys `.text()`?