# Secure Node.js chat (avoid XSS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, socket.io, xss

I'm building a simple little chat with Node.js and socket.io

When a user types his message, it is broadcasted to all other users.

Server sends the message :

```
io.sockets.emit('fromServerToClient', { "message": message });
```

Client displays it :

```
socket.on('fromServerToClient', function (data) {
    $('#messages').append(data.message + '<br />');
});
```

But when you send something like `<script>alert(1);</script>`, it is executed on every client browser.

This is a serious security flaw and I want to avoid it as much as possible.
I've seen people escape `&, <, > and "` characters, but I don't think it's enough!

How can I be 100% sure of not having a XSS vulnerability on my chat?

By the way, I always specify the charset to avoid UTF-7 attacks.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `.html()` because that's basically `eval` on steroids - capable of causing the interpretation of a good variety of languages.

Text is always interpreted as text though:

```
$('#messages').append($("<div>", {
    text: data.message
}));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very good answer. I didn't think it would be so simple and I can say it works great.

Answer (score 3):

The best way here, is for the server to do nothing!

Yes, you read that right. The correct place to "escape" content is where it's being outputted, in the context where it's being outputted. This is known as Filter-In, Escape out.

So in your case, the client should handle the escaping for you. Funny enough, jQuery (which it looks like you're using) has a method that does this for you: `$.fn.text()`. So your client code becomes:

```
socket.on('fromServerToClient', function (data) {
    $('#messages').append($('<div></div>').text(data.message));
});
```

I added the `div` so that each message can be styled appropriately...

But your server side should have nothing to do with this *escaping*.

Now, you could decide to filter out anything that looks like HTML on the server, which would be known as Filtering (and either replace it away, or reject it). But definitely do not escape it!

Comment: be careful: "the client should handle the escaping for you" is not always a good idea. For example, imagine your client escapes the message before sending it (the one who talks is the one who escapes the text). This would be a security problem, as the client can manipulate the escaping code to not escape anything. So take care when choosing the right client!

Comment: @TheBronx: It is *always* a good idea, and in most cases the only way to achieve actual security. Note that by "client" I mean whatever is actually displaying it (injecting it into HTML). If your server renders the HTML, than the server would do the escaping. As far as escaping before sending it, that's wrong from the start and that's why that would be insecure. Filter In, Escape Out is very well defined and known to work. If you deviate from that, it's on you... The client *must* escape it before *outputting* the data. Not before sending it...

Comment: @ircmaxell I know what you want to say, and I think it is correct. But it can be confusing for a newbie, because in a chat both the one who writes and the one who reads are "clients" of the app. Just wanted to clarify, sorry.